# jest test async function fail

Tags: typescript, async-await, jestjs

I have a simple typescript function which just prints some text and sleep. The test finished without waiting for the async function to return.

This is my function.

```
test('sleep test', () => {
    function sleep(ms: number) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    async function delayedGreeting() {
        console.log('Hello');
        await sleep(5000);
        console.log('World!');
        await sleep(5000);
        console.log('Goodbye!');
    }

    delayedGreeting();
});
```

The test ended with only 'Hello' in the console.

I tried other forms suggested by this website https://www.sitepoint.com/delay-sleep-pause-wait/. My test always ends with printing 'Hello' only.

The skeleton of the project is generated from create-react-app with typescript option. 
I have these dependencies in my project.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^12.12.47",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/zeromq": "^4.6.3",
    "protobuf-typescript": "^6.8.8",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5",
    "zeromq": "^6.0.0-beta.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5"
  },
```

And I use `npm test` to run my test.

Is this something to do with Jest? How do I fix this in my test? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The test isn't supposed to wait for asynchronous task because it's synchronous. Jest exits early because it has nothing to wait, this can be debugged with [detectOpenHandles](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#--detectopenhandles) option.

Jest [supports promises](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#promises) for asynchronous tests, it should be:

```
test('sleep test', async () => {
    await delayedGreeting();
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test calls `delayedGreeting()` that prints `Hello` then starts an asynchronous operation and returns. The `await` statement work as expected only if the function that uses it is `await`-ed itself (and so on).

Jest is not waiting for your async flow to complete because nobody told it to do so.

You can move the `sleep()` and `delayedGreeting()` functions outside the test, to make the test easier to read.

```
function sleep(ms: number) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function delayedGreeting() {
    console.log('Hello');
    await sleep(5000);
    console.log('World!');
    await sleep(5000);
    console.log('Goodbye!');
}
```

The easiest way to make the test work is to declare the test implementation function as `async` and let it `await delayedGreeting()`:

```
test('sleep test', async () => {
    await delayedGreeting();
});
```

This way Jest knows that it has to wait for the test function that waits for `delayedGreeting()` that, in turn, waits for the two `Promise`s returned by the two calls of `sleep()` to complete.